# PHP: sqlsrv_fetch_array() returns false

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm encountering a strange issue, where `sqlsrv_query()` returns a valid statement resource, but `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` subsequently returns false. I tested my query (`$q`) in MS SQL Server Management Studio, so I know it returns a result with a certain number of rows. The code I have is...

```
$r = @sqlsrv_query($dbcMssql, $q, array(), array('Scrollable'=>'static'));    // works
$rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($r);    // this shows there are correct number of rows
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($r, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);    // $row is FALSE
```

I'm using the same bit of a code on another MSSQL database, and it is working without any problem. The only difference with this MSSQL DB is that it uses BIGINT for its primary key and some of the column names are different (not that this matters).

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Whilte `$stmt` is not false, I looked at the error anyway, and it gives me

```
        [0] => IMSSP
        [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
        [1] => -35
        [code] => -35
        [2] => Invalid type
        [message] => Invalid type
```

The IMSSP leads me to believe that, according to documentation at `http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php`, it's my SQL for PHP 2.0 driver that is causing the problem. I see that SQL for PHP 3.0 has been released. This could be the problem I suppose.. because the DB i'm trying to query is a newer version of MSSQL (2008? vs 2005) than the one I've been using previously without any problems. However, this driver has been compiled with VC9 only (2.0 was available for both), and my PHP 5.3 is compiled with VC6.. so it will not load. Does this mean I need to recompile it using the source code or re-install PHP with a VC9 version?

I don't know how to recompile, so I guess re-installing VC9 version of PHP 5.3 is the way to go for me right now.

Comment: Remove the `@` sign and see if you get an error

Comment: Hi John, I tried that as well. There wasn't any errors.

Comment: I removed the `$stmt === false` check for the error because `sqlsrv_query()` isn't returning false. So, there is an error, but it' just wasn't being caught by the if-statement of the `sqlsrv_error()` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably something wrong with your query. You can retrieve the error message with `sqlsrv_errors()`, e.g. like this:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($tsql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Please look at my updated post above. sqlsrv_query() doesn't return false, but there is still an error originating from the MS's SQL for PHP 2.0 driver I'm using.

Comment: @user796837 Well the error message says "Invalid type", so I would go about checking whether all the inputs are correct. For instance, have you tried passing `array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC)` instead of just `static`? I can't see how exactly you come to the conclusion, that this is a version problem. It just says, that IMSSP are errors originating from errors within the driver, not the database.

Comment: Hey mahok, I've narrowed down the problem to a word in my query (please note that this query works in MS SQL Server Management Studio). An Exmaple query looks like.. `"SELECT * FROM [db_name].[dbo].[table_name] WHERE OrderID = '47725006';"`. It works for any `table_name` EXCEPT for `table_name='Order'`. For reason, `[Order]` is determined to be invalid.. any ideas?

Comment: Order is a reserver word, so I'm guessing this is causing you trouble. But since you escape it using the brackets, this should not be a problem...

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I've created a more succinct and relevant post here if you have any solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056616/ms-sql-escaping-reserved-words/11056627#11056627

Answer (score 1):

This error 'Invalid Type' happens when the query returns a column type which PDO can't handle. For example you will get this when you try to

```
SELECT default_value FROM sys.parameters
```

as that column is type sql_variant. If it makes sense, rather CAST that column to varchar or whatever, or eliminate it from the query.