# Escaping reserved SQL Server keywords through PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

A query I wrote in PHP for a SQL Server database is having an issue where a word is not being recognized as the table name. I'm using SQL Server for PHP 2.0 (VC6). The following query works and returns all orders from the table `Order` when executed in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
SELECT * FROM "db_name"."dbo"."Order" (also tried using brakets [] around table name)
```

In PHP, I get the following error:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => IMSSP
        [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
        [1] => -35
        [code] => -35
        [2] => Invalid type
        [message] => Invalid type
    )
```

This query works within the PHP code for all other tables in the database, `db_name`.. it just won't work for table `Order`, and that is the correct table name. I tried double quote, rectangular brackets, no quote/bracket, etc. to to no avail. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

**** UPDATE:

I found a solution to this. Please take a look at one of the answers for the fix or work-around.

Comment: What is the exact SQL query used in the PHP code, and what driver/adapter is being used?

Comment: Have you been researched the actual PHP error code that you've received?

Comment: The exact query being used is in the post (database name replaced by `dB_name`). I'm using MS SQL for PHP 2.0 for the driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something must be going on in PHP or your driver.  You should be able to use the SQL Server Profiler to see the actual query being submitted.

In any case, if you can't find out what it's doing.  You could consider this as a workaround:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyOrder
AS
SELECT * FROM [Order]
```

And move on - life's too short.

Comment: So, is there a reason why views I make through PHP doesn't show up on MSSQL Mgnt Studio and vice versa. I'm using `Select VIEW_DEFINITION From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;` to see the views. Anyhow, I tried making a view for the table `OrderItem` and used this view to retrieve rows via PHP. This works. However, for the table `Order`, it still doesn't work. I made

Comment: Views I made (all done in the PHP code): `CREATE VIEW myOrderItems AS SELECT * FROM [db_name].[dbo].[OrderItem];` and `CREATE VIEW myOrders AS SELECT * FROM [db_name].[dbo].[Order];`. `SELECT FROM myOrderItems WHERE OrderID='1234';` works.  `SELECT FROM myOrders WHERE OrderID='1234';` doesn't work.

Comment: One more thing: `sqlsrv_error()` doesn't yield an error. It's NULL.

Comment: @user796837 Creating the views from PHP might still be subject to the same issues you are having with escaping in PHP in the first place.  Why not create the views in SSMS?  They would be schema objects and live in the database permanently.

Comment: @user796837 Did you check with the profiler to see what wuery is actually being submitted to SQL Server, whether the query got mangled in some way by PHP or the driver?

Comment: That's the one of the problems. Creating the views in SSMS doesn't show through PHP and vice versa. It's as if I'm mistakenly connected to the wrong DB, but when I query other tables to make sure, I get the right rows both in PHP and SMSS.

Comment: About the SQL profiler, how do I use it or where do I find it? I'm reading about what it is, but not how to use it.

Comment: @user796837 There are a number of tutorials around - but have a look at this one: http://thefirstsql.com/2011/01/07/sql-server-profiler-a-tutorial/

Comment: Hm.. I don't have the profile because I have SMSS Express. Do I need the full version of SMSS (which seems like I need to purchase: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb671149.aspx)?

Comment: @user796837 When you CREATE VIEW without a schema prefix like dbo, it goes in the default schema for that user (which may not be dbo).

Comment: @user796837 There is also the option of server-side tracing: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/server_side_tracing_in_sql_server.htm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188662(v=sql.105)

Comment: Cade Roux: well, I'll be damned. I found a solution, and I'm posting it as the answer. Please take a look for reference. I might have you quote you some time on "And move on - life's too short." Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution to my problem. Here are my specs:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- PHP 5.3 VC9-compiled (updated it from VC^ version while trying to solve this problem)
- Driver: SQL for PHP 2.0 (VC9)
- Table name from which I was trying to pull data: `[Order]`
- Query I was using: `SELECT * FROM [db_name].[dbo].[Order] WHERE ...`

The above query was not working for the `Order` table at all from PHP, while it worked fine in SSMS. All of the other tables in `db_name` queried well, too. I tried creating a view or using an alias, and none of them worked for `Order`.

It should have occurred to me from the get-go, but I finally tried to just querying one column, like `[OrderID]`, and what do you know? It works as long as you list, one by one, the column names in the query. I believe one of the column in MSSQL is not supported in MySQL. So,

`SELECT [OrderID],[OrderNumber],... FROM [db_name].[dbo].[Order] WHERE ...`

works perfectly fine! I hope this will save someone some agony in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the query returns a column type which PDO can't handle. For example you will get this when you try to

```
SELECT default_value FROM sys.parameters
```

as that column is type sql_variant. If it makes sense, rather CAST that column to varchar or whatever, or eliminate it from the query.

Probably what happened in your case was that there was a column on that table that was of a strange type which was eliminated when you explicitly named the columns that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A table can't be named "order" : that's a [reserved word in SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

There are a lot of situations where you may use this name between quotes (or back-quotes) but you'll always end in a situation where you can't handle it. Rename this table.

If you can't try aliasing it :

```
SELECT * FROM "db_name"."dbo"."Order" as ord
```

Comment: When *can't* a quoted identifier be used? (That is, in *what syntax construct*? I don't disagree that a better name should be chosen...)

Comment: But it is named `Order` in the third party program I'm connecting to. If I change this table name, it will break the program. Is there a way to escape the word `Order` or use an alias, so it doesn't conflict with the reserved word? I thought [] or "" escaped any strings?

Comment: In most databases (including SQL Server), reserved words can be used as table names as long as they're enclosed in double quotes (or brackets in SQL Server's case).

Comment: But not with every drivers. The problem seems to come here from the mapping. That's why I suggest also an alias.